# Basic login authentication fails after upgrading tomcat-embeded versions

Tags: java, web.xml, embedded-tomcat-7

My application expose web applications using Tomcat Embedded.
It is secured using username and password authentication. From my web.xml

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>BMC Application Diagnostics Portal Console</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

I'm implementing my own Realm and I'm configuring it in my Tomcat instance:

```
_tomcat.setDefaultRealm(new MyRealm());
```

Everything worked just fine, until I had to upgrade tomcat's version (to 7.0.30 minimum). After upgrading both tomcat-embed-core.jar and tomcat-embed-jasper.jar I just can't access my web application.
The authentication window pops up, I insert my username and password but it fail to login (seems like username\password incorrect behavior).
I didn't change nothing in my code! If I swap the jars back to 7.0.22 everything works just fine.

BTW, [setDefaultRealm()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html#getDefaultRealm%28%29) is deprecated, I don't know if it helps.

If someone had this problem before or has an idea how to handle this it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52443). Since version 7.0.24 Realm should be set to Engine, as follows:

```
_tomcat.getEngine().setRealm(new MyRealm());
```